# Swift framework - Header and Module folder empty after build

Tags: ios, swift, ios-frameworks

I created a CocoaTouch framework in Swift. Added few files. But when I build the project, the header and module folder inside the framework are empty.

[image]

[image]

This is the header section in project settings :

[image]

Comment: Usually there will be only header file available if you have not deleted the default one provided by Xcode. If you are using obj c, then you can go to built settings of the project and add the headers that you want to be part of the framework.

Comment: @Satyam : Added the screenshot of header section.